# IPTables: allow SSH access only, nothing else in or out

Tags: firewall, iptables, godaddy

How do you configure IPTables so that it will **only** allow SSH in, and allow no other traffic in **or out**?

Any safety precautions anyone can recommend?

I have a server that I *believe* has been migrated away from GoDaddy successfully and I *believe* is no longer in use.

But I want to make sure just because ... you never know. :)

Note that this is a virtual dedicated server from GoDaddy... That means no backup and virtually no support.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need just to set the default policy to DROP on the INPUT and OUTPUT chains.

To allow SSH in, you need the following commands:

```
$ sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
$ sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The last two commands allow loopback traffic as this is required by some applications to function correctly.
You can restrict the SSH access from specific IP using `-s source_ip` option.

Executing the commands in order as shown above will cause your current SSH session to hang. This is because iptables commands take effect immediately. You need to execute them in a shell script to avoid losing the ability to connect to your machine when executing them remotely.

Comment: `--state RELATED` on the last rule is unnecessary; `--state ESTABLISHED` is enough.  You may also wish to allow DNS traffic, and probably should allow anything on the loopback interface, or all sorts of things may behave very oddly.

Comment: @MadHatter: Yes, you are right especially about the loopback stuff :)

Comment: Thanks, would it be possible to get the entire file from you?  ie, something I can copy and paste straight into /etc/sysconfig/iptables?  I'm not experienced enough with this to trust my intuition to make the proper edits.

Comment: @Disco: I updated my answer

Comment: ps. establish connection will be force closed after first command

Comment: @Userpassword: You should execute these commands as a script or execute them directly on the machine (using keyboard and screen). This is because the commands take action immediately.

Comment: Example this solution not close SSH: session https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-port-knocking-to-hide-your-ssh-daemon-from-attackers-on-ubuntu

Comment: You should really change the order of these commands. The Policy lines should appear as the last ones. Anyone just copypasting this into an ssh session will be HUPed and shut out immediately

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT  # or iptables -P INPUT DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT # or iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: I think you mean `-i lo` not `-s lo`; again, only `ESTABLISHED` is needed in the state rules, and there should probably be a `--sport 22` in there, too.  Why is everyone so keen to allow `RELATED`?

Comment: @MadHatter: About `RELATED`: It's actually useful for matching stuff that is non-TCP, like ping replies and DNS replies. At least, that's what I'd always assumed.

Comment: My belief is that it will match neither of those.  It would match, for example, an ICMP host-administratively-prohibited response, but that's about as helpful as it gets; and if not qualified, it will match any related traffic, not just traffic related to the previous line.

Comment: @MadHatter: I guess I'll have to run a few tests to see if you're right. Thanks for challenging my assumption.

Comment: Yep, the ESTABLISHED state is all that's needed to match UDP DNS replies and ICMP echo-replies.

Comment: Thanks for picking that up MadHatter.  RELATED?  It says things like ICMP errors (hopefully related to the connection attempt) are "RELATED".  So if the server is not running, you'd get an ICMP port unreachable immediately.  But honestly, it's just an incantation I now type without thinking.  What's the downside?